# Google Sheets (Drop Down list to change data in rows below)

Tags: google-sheets

I can't seem to find any information about this particular issue anywhere, unbelievable.

I'm trying to change the rows with Balance, Weekly PnL, Weekly PnL% etc. to go with the weeks.

So the rows in week 1 would have different data from the rows in week 2 and 3 etc.

Can this even be done in Google Sheets?
[[image]

Comment: Which data should be in week 1, week 2 etc?

Comment: I would just like to be able to access the different weeks from the dropdown menu, without the same data from week 1 carrying over to the other weeks.

So if I access Week 2, I can enter in the data on that week, and then go back to Week 1 and it would have the data from Week 1.

I don't know how else to explain it haha :))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have sheet `Data` with the following format:

| Week | # | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Week 1 | Balance | 1 |
| Week 2 | Balance | 2 |
| Week 3 | Balance | 3 |
| Week 1 | Weekly PnL | 4 |
| Week 2 | Weekly PnL | 5 |
| Week 3 | Weekly PnL | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... |

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,FILTER(Data!B:C,Data!A:A=B1),2,FALSE)))
```